# Parametrization of integer solutions of $k^2(m^3n-mn^3)=l^2(uv^3-u^3v)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, parametrization

What is the parametrization of integer solutions of the equation
$$k^2(m^3n-mn^3)=l^2(uv^3-u^3v)$$
I am looking for the general form of integer solutions to this equation, where I can plug in any integer to the general form to get a set of integer solutions to the equation. It should include every integer solutions to the equation.

I know that the equation can be rephrased as $$k^2mn(m^2-n^2)=l^2uv(v^2-u^2)$$
and
$$k^2mn(m+n)(m-n)=l^2uv(v+u)(v-u)$$

Comment: Try to match the sides of the equation $$k = l\;and\;m=v\;and\;n = u$$

Comment: @Moustapha_M_I But, that wouldn't include all of the solutions.

Comment: This is directly related to the congruent number problem.

Comment: @Hisham, Solution for $k=l$. 
    $(m,n,u,v)=(-(a-b)(-3b^2+a^2)(-b^2-4ab+3a^2),\ (a+b)(-b^2+3a^2)(-3b^2-4ab+a^2),\  
    
     -(a-b)(-3b^2+4ab+a^2)(-b^2+3a^2),\ (a+b)(-b^2+4ab+3a^2)(-3b^2+a^2))$
    $a,b$ are arbitrary integers.

Comment: @Tomita Does this iclude every integer solution where $k=l$? If you don't mind, can you send how did you get that?

Comment: @Hisham, It's a partial solution. I guess there are other parametric solutions.

Comment: @Hisham,There is a solution such as $(k,m,n)=(l/2,u+v,u-v)$

Comment: @Tomita If $l$ is odd, $k$ is not going to be an integer.

Comment: @Hisham,Yes, set $l$ to an even number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify matters, let $k = l$ as suggested in the comments. Then the pair of  equations,

$$mn(m^2+n^2)=uv(v^2+u^2)\tag1$$
$$mn(m^2-n^2)=uv(v^2-u^2)\tag2$$

where the second one is yours can be translated, respectively, into familiar forms,

$$(m - n)^4 + (u + v )^4 = (m + n )^4 + (u - v )^4\tag3$$
$$(m - n z)^4 + (u z + v )^4 = (m + n z)^4 + (u z - v)^4\tag4$$

with the *imaginary unit* $z=\sqrt{-1}$.

It is known that $(3)$ does not have a complete parameterization, so  presumably likewise for $(4)$. However, starting with the solutions in the comments, then using elliptic curves, one can generate as many polynomial solutions to $(1)$ or $(2)$ as one wishes.

Comment: How do you translate the equation to $(3)$ and $(4)$?

Comment: @Hisham Just expand $(3)$ and you will end up with $(1)$. This [Wolfram command](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Factor%5B%28m+-+n%29%5E4+%2B+%28u+%2B+v+%29%5E4+-+%28%28m+%2B+n+%29%5E4+%2B+%28u+-+v+%29%5E4%29%5D) should do it. Likewise for $(4)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: Can you provide the reason for $(3)$ not having complete parametrization?

Comment: @Hisham The equation $a^n+b^n = c^n+d^n$ of which $(3)$ is the special case $n=4$ is very well-studied. The cases $n=2,3$ have _complete_ polynomial parameterizations. However, when you go to $n=4$ you hit the obstacle of elliptic curves, which _cannot_ be completely parameterized by polynomials. And if you go even higher up to $n=5$, it is conjectured it doesn't even have solutions in the integers. Thus, the higher you go, you lose something, just like its  more well-known cousin $a^n+b^n = c^n$.